# Upload File using Robot Framework on Safari

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework, safaridriver

Upload File keyword is not working on Safari. I have this test running on Chrome, but when comes to Safari, I got this message:

```
Choose File id=files file_path=<path>
```

InvalidArgumentException: Message: One or more files could not be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload File is not supported :(

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4220